# Using memcpy or memcmp with ranges

Tags: c, arrays, memcpy, memcmp

Is it possible to use a range when using memcpy or memcmp?

```
char data[900000]; // size 900000
char array[20]; // size 20

if (memcmp(data[50-70], array, 20) == 0) {
    // do thing
}
```

I'd like to be able to compare the (20) keys data[50-70] with array[]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`memcmp` / `memcpy` simply take a pointer to the data you want to compare or copy.

Thus, you can essentially copy or compare any "range" by providing a pointer to the start of the data you wish to compare and the length of the data, pretty much as you have done above.

Adjust your code above as follows:

```
if (memcmp(&data[50], array, 20) == 0) {
    // do thing
}
```

This tells `memcmp` to start checking at the address of the 50th subscript of the data array, and to compare that to the data at the address of array, and to check 20 elements.

Comment: oh wow that's awesome. one more question — let's say i had an integer `n = 10` would this work: `if (memcmp(&data[50+n], array, 20) == 0)`?

Comment: Yes, it would start checking at the address of the 50th + n element of your array. If you are new to C and pointers in general I would strongly suggest reading some pointer tutorials online as they are a fundamental part of the language and obtaining a solid understanding of them early will help you considerably! :)